# position:sticky failing down the page

Tags: css

Hoping someone can help with this. Have a menu bar that is set to `position:sticky`. It starts at 50px from the top on page load. When the document is scrolled, the menu bar sticks at the top of the page, as expected, until it "hits" another element further down the page, at which point it's scrolled above the top of the viewport, along with everything else.

Originally, I thought it was "running" into flex item(s) or something that had `position:relative`.  That's not the case.

Has anyone come across this? I'd provide a code sample, but I'm not entirely sure what is causing the issue.

Comment: where's your HTMl and CSS so that we could have a look at it?

Answer (score 3):

MDN: `Sticky positioning can be thought of as a hybrid of relative and fixed positioning. A stickily positioned element is treated as relatively positioned until it crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is treated as fixed until it reaches the boundary of its parent.`

Note that sticky, by specification, will not work inside element with overflow: hidden or auto

Use this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Example:

The sticky button always moves till its parent div's edges.

```css
section {
  height: 200vh;
  display: flex;
}
section nav {
  background: wheat;
  width: 30vw;
  display: flex;
}
section nav button.btn {
  background: #9b59b6;
  border: 0px;
  color: white;
  flex: 1;
  max-height: 50px;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
section div {
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
}

header, footer {
  text-align:center;
  background: #2c3e50;
  color:white;
}

header{
  padding:1rem;
}
footer{
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<header>Scroll the page to see the sticky effect.</header>
<section> 
  <nav>
    <button class="btn">Sticky Button</button>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <article>Hello!</article>
  </div>
</section>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```